# How can I use such given limit to show the derivative of the function?

Tags: limits, derivatives

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Le0t3.png)

I tried to solve that using the first principle, but I am failing to get it. How can I approach that question. 
The question is: given that lim h=0 (e^(h)+1)÷h=1, use such given fact to show that the derivative of 2e^(2x) -e^(-x)+5x is 4e^(2x) -e^(-x)+5. 
I can differentiate without such given instruction, but to adhere to that instruction, I can not.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What has your question to do with `ordinary-differential-equations`?

Comment: I thought it it's part of differentiation, finding derivatives and limits,  I am sorry.

Comment: Please do not put images.

Comment: Can't you write down the definition of the derivative as a limit ?

Comment: The function to be differentiated? 2e^(2x)-e^(-x)+5x

Comment: Are you answering me ?

Comment: The derivative of function f at x=c is the limit of the slope of the secant line from x=c to x=c+h as h approaches 0. Symbolically, this is the limit of [f(c)-f(c+h)]/h as h→0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us begin by separating the terms of the expression and approaching them independent of each other. The derivative with respect to $x$ of $5x$ is trivial and does not involve $e$.
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[2e^{2x}-e^{-x}+5x\right]&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[2e^{2x}\right]+\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[-e^{-x}\right]+\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[5x\right]\\&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[2e^{2x}\right]+\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[-e^{-x}\right]+5
\end{align}
Now, we can treat each remaining term as if it is its own function of $x$ and use the limit definition of a derivative. This will allow us to apply the limit you provided. Let's do $2e^{2x}$ first, then we will do $-e^{-x}$.
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[2e^{2x}\right]=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{2e^{2(x+h)}-2e^{2x}}{h}=2\cdot\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{e^{2x}(e^{2h}-1)}{h}=2\cdot\lim\limits_{h\to0}(e^{2x})\cdot\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{e^{2h}-1}{h}$$
We're almost finished here. Notice the limit laws that we applied. Notice, too, the difference of squares in the numerator.
$$2\cdot\lim\limits_{h\to0}(e^{2x})\cdot\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{e^{2h}-1}{h}=2e^{2x}\cdot\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{(e^h+1)(e^h-1)}{h}=2e^{2x}\cdot\lim\limits_{h\to0}(e^h+1)\cdot\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{e^h-1}{h}$$
We have now reached the limit statement provided and will utilize it as asked.
$$2e^{2x}\cdot\lim\limits_{h\to0}(e^h+1)\cdot\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{e^h-1}{h}=2e^{2x}\cdot(e^0+1)\cdot1=2e^{2x}\cdot2=4e^{2x}$$
We have utilized the provided limit statement once now, and we will do it once more in the second term. Here, it is very important to remember what negative exponents mean.
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[-e^{-x}\right]=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{-e^{-(x+h)}+e^{-x}}{h}=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{-\frac{1}{e^{x+h}}+\frac{1}{e^x}}{h}=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{\frac{e^h}{e^{x+h}}-\frac{1}{e^{x+h}}}{h}$$
We can multiply the numerator by the reciprocal of the denominator, which is $1/h$.
$$\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{\frac{e^h-1}{e^{x+h}}}{h}=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{e^h-1}{he^{x+h}}=\lim\limits_{h\to0}(e^{-(x+h)})\cdot\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{e^h-1}{h}=e^{-x-0}\cdot1=e^{-x}$$
We have utilized the provided limit statement twice in this problem to evaluate the derivative. The key to solving this problem was an understanding of the limit definition of a derivative, limit laws, and algebraic manipulation.
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[2e^{2x}-e^{-x}+5x\right]=4e^{2x}+e^{-x}+5$$